# How do I Parse this Date String in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following date string Tue Jan 06 2015 17:31:25 GMT-0500

When i try to parse it i'm getting the following exception:
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
model.UpdatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Jan 06 2015 17:31:25 GMT-0500", "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is the date and time format strings list.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `ZZZZ` is a valid format specifier. Try this format string:

```
"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz"
```

Comment: @Alao: Note also the need to put the `GMT` in single quotes, to specify it as a literal string in the format.

Comment: I was using the JavaScript library momment to convert the Json date into a usable format.  I ended up removing the GMT.